# Angular 4, a warning from a unknown package cause: Failed to compile. ./~/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, package, angular-cli

I am not sure where this is coming from, or how to fix it.

```
WARNING in ./~/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js
9:12-34 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
webpack: Compiled with warnings.
```

But in the latest version of Angular Cli this cause the application not to compile / run at all...

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-po-http-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.1",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.12",
    "ng2-signalr": "^2.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "signalr": "^2.2.1",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same error since I have added ngx-translate and ngx-translate-po-http-loader

Comment: https://github.com/biesbjerg/ngx-translate-po-http-loader/issues/2